# url query parameters gives other values with htaccess apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am learning about url rewriting on .htaccess and is there any good book where i can learn.

I building an RESTfull webservices and i am working with pretty urls

Now I wrote below syntax in .htaccess file to achieve other urls.

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/users/([0-9a-zA-Z]) users.php?key=$1&format=$2&uid=$3
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/users users.php?key=$1&format=$2
```

### Example 1

And url i tried and result are mentioned below

```
e.g.    http://localhost/site/key/format/users/user_id


http://localhost/rest/r123/json/users/pGQqAMbVQAFx
```

### test.php

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

And only get values for `key` and `format` not `uid` and value for `key` is `php` and i dont know how php value comes into exists

### output.

```
Array
(
    [key] => php
    [format] => json
)
```

### Example 2

```
http://localhost/rest/r123/json/users/
```

### output

```
Array
(
    [key] => r123
    [format] => json
)
```

And is there any good book on url rewriting for beginners other than apache documentation.

Comment: tried that.. not working

Comment: ***Pro Tip:*** Do not write multiple rewrite rules for multiple URLs. Write one RewriteRule for all URLs. Use the PHP script then to further parse the incomming request.

Comment: And btw, your problem description is problematic. There is no such thing as "wrong values" with modrewrite. The software just works and what it does is documented. So in 99.9% of the cases here on the website it is not modrewrite that does wrong, but a user making use of it without understanding it. And try to wrap your head around the apache documentation (write your own tutorial based on it), it is quite complete and should be your first stop. Just saying, this is how I could survive the changes across multiple server versions easily (okay easily is not true :), but it worked).

Comment: I won't lie I'm slightly confused as to why the wrong values are being given. But having looked into URL rewriting I can suggest some good websites and / books that you might find useful. [Url Rewriting for Beginners (Online Resource)](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) [Some Examples You may find useful.](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html/) [A useful book that I still use for a lot of my Apache related SEO. ](http://amzn.to/11pgwbF) Hope some of these help for future reference and that soembody is able to help you i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules had few issues. Here is the fixed code:

```
RewriteRule /([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/users/([0-9a-z]+)/? users.php?key=$1&format=$2&uid=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/users/?$ users.php?key=$1&format=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Issues/Fixes in your code:**

1. After `users/` you had this regex: `([0-9a-zA-Z])` which will match single character you probably meant `([0-9a-zA-Z]+)`
2. You should use flags L (Last Rule), QSA (Query String Append), NC (Ignore Case) after each Rewrite rule.
3. Consider using end anchor `$` to avoid matching unwanted URIs.
4. Use / at the start of regex to avoid matching unwanted URIs.
5. Instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]` you can use `[a-z0-9]` and use `NC` flag as described above.

Read more about mod_rewritw flags: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Fixing it for copy & pasting is teaching nothing. Would you be proud to keep other users dumb?

Comment: @hakre, Don't get me wrong mate, I am still spending my time in listing all the reasons for fixing it.

Comment: Well, you must have some super-powers, like knowing that QSA is wanted. Also OP wrote the he has problems with the Apache manual, so just listing flags will not tell him much. But I'll review your question later so I can take my DV back if I see it is not just any longer.

Comment: @hakre: `Well, you must have some super-powers,` You're such a senior pro on SO, may I know the reasons for this tone? I don't have any such powers, found some mistakes in OP's code and fixed it, provided my reasons for fixing it. I don't see what's wrong in that.

Comment: Wrong and right is so much in the eye of the beholder, so we should not judge that much about that. And sorry if my tone offended you, rest assured it was with the best intentions and not at all to offend you. I'm generally fine with your answer and especially the edits. I just have commented it.

Comment: @anubhava It that worked for me when i remove those `/` at start of regex its working perfect.. and one up for flags..